# How do you list queue members with Twilio PHP SDK

Tags: php, twilio-php

I have been trying for hours to list out Twilio hold queue members with their hold times, etc, etc without success using the Twilio PHP sdk/helper.

The very basics of my code:

```
$twilio = new Client($sid,$token);
$queues = $twilio->queues('QUXXXXXXX')->members('')->fetch();
```

I could put a call Sid in members() but I need the list of call Sids. If I leave it empty doing a var_dump shows me that there is a [queue_members] elemnet that has all the array elements with the data I need in it, but I cant figure out for the life of me how to get at it. I would think this this would be easy, and it probably is, but Im not able to translate Twilio's documentation into what else would work in this scenario that I havent already tried 10 different ways.

I am trying to learn the Twilio PHP wrapper, as I am pretty familiar with using their API using just curl.

Thanks

Comment: _"var_dump shows me"_ - can you show _us_? Because what trouble you are having with accessing data in a structure we know nothing about, is hard to tell ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the `members` property of the queue.

This is of the [`Queue\MemberList` type](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/7.12.1/classes/Twilio_Rest_Api_V2010_Account_Queue_MemberList.html#methods).

Then either [read](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/7.12.1/classes/Twilio_Rest_Api_V2010_Account_Queue_MemberList/read.html) or [stream](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/7.12.1/classes/Twilio_Rest_Api_V2010_Account_Queue_MemberList/stream.html) member instances from it.

The following code snippet logs the `uri` property of the `Queue\MemberInstance`.
Look up [other accessible properties in the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-php/7.12.1/source/Twilio/Rest/Api/V2010/Account/Queue/MemberInstance.php.html#line28).

```php
# Read example
$members = $twilio->queues('QUx')->members->read();

foreach($members as $member) {
    echo $member->uri;
};

# Stream example
$memberStream = $twilio->queues('QUx')->members->stream();

foreach($memberStream as $member) {
    echo $member->uri;
};
```